# Problem with LSTM __call__ initial_state parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have this piece of code:

```
s = Input(shape=(self.s_length,), name="s")
z = Input(shape=(self.z_length,), name="z")
decoder_inputs = [s, z]

# latent.shape: (None, self.s_length + self.z_length)
latent = Concatenate(name="latent_concat")([s, z])

# get initial state of high decoder
# init_state.shape: (None, X_high_size)
init_state = Dense(X_high_size, activation="tanh", name="hidden_state_init")(latent)

# high decoder produces embeddings
# h_X.shape: (None, n_embeddings, self.s_length + self.z_length)
h_X = RepeatVector(n_embeddings, name="latent_repeat")(latent)
for l in range(X_high_depth):
    h_X = LSTM(
        X_high_size,
        return_sequences=True,
        activation="relu",
        name=f"high_encoder_{l}"
    )(h_X, initial_state=[init_state, init_state])
```

When I run it, during *training* time I get the error:

```
File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/mygan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1215, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/mygan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2666, in __call__
    return self._call(inputs)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/mygan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2636, in _call
    fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/mygan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1382, in __call__
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/xxx/anaconda3/envs/mygan/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 519, in __exit__
    c_api.TF_GetCode(self.status.status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 's' with dtype float and shape [?,16]
     [[Node: s = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[?,16], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"]()]]
     [[Node: loss_2/z_discriminator_loss/Mean_3/_1073 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_41285_loss_2/z_discriminator_loss/Mean_3", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]]
```

(`16` is the input `s` dimension, by the way. )
However I noticed that if I just *omit* the `initial_state=[init_state, init_state]` argument from the LSTM layer call, everything runs smoothly.
The code seems correct to me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong...might be a Keras bug?

Answer (score 0):

A placeholder is an empty input tensor that is expecting to receive the data when fitting or predicting. 
If you specify the "initial state", the LSTM expects real data, real numbers, while when you call them, the placeholder is still not populated.